# Bootstrap navbar button not working on mobile or any devices

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

My navbar is not functioning properly on mobile devices the button is doing nothing at all.

Originally there was no button or navigation however I've placed the button within the navbar.

This doesnt seem to be doing anything and I have probably just not spotted the simplest mistake.

Any help? Thank you in advance.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container container-fixed">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
        <img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="CraftZealous">
      </a>

      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="defaultNavbar1" aria-controls="defaultNavbar1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="defaultNavbar1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navi">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item "><a href="/Info">Info</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item "><a href="/staff">Staff Team</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item "><a href="/quests" target="_blank">Quests</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item "><a href="/news">Latest News</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <?php if ($session->logged_in) { ?>
            <?php if ($session->isAdmin()) { ?>
                <li class="nav-link nav-item"><a href="/admin/admin" class="admincolor" target="_blank">AdminCP</a></li>
            <?php } ?>

            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a href="" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle usercolor" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><?php echo $session->username ?></a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="/profile?user=<?php echo $session->username; ?>">Profile</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="/profile-settings">Account settings</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="process">Log out &raquo;</a>
                </div>
            </li>
    <?php } else { ?>

        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login">Log in</a></li>
        <li><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
        <?php } ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the hash to your `data-target` like so:

```
data-target="#defaultNavbar1"
```

Comment: Thank you, thought it would be something like that just couldn't spot it. Appreciate it!